# React Navigation check if previous screen exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am looking desperately for a possibility to check if a previous screen exists in ReactNavigation.

Using `this.props.navigation.goBack()` returns `false` if no previous route exists, but I can not use it because if a previous route exists I get redirected.

Is there a possibility to check if I opened the app instead of navigated from another screen to the Home screen?

Thank you. I am not using Redux. It would make such stuff easier but I would like to avoid using it at the moment.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What could be a solution (not sure that it's the best one) would be to spend in the param object the previous screen. With that, if the params exists would mean that a previous screen exists.

For example:

```
const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
  routeName: 'Profile',

  params: { previous_screen: 'CURRENT_SCREEN' },

  action: NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'NEXT_SCREEN' }),
});

this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
```

And then in the next screen:

```
const { navigation } = this.props;
if (navigation.state.params && navigation.state.params.previous_screen) {
  // A previous screen exists
} else {
  // No previous screen
}
```

Comment: should'nt dere be some way to check from which screen did we land to this screen? rather than passing an unused param.

Answer (score 10):

As of React Navigation 5 you can use `useNavigationState` hook inside functional component this way:

```js
const routesLength = useNavigationState(state => state.routes.length);
console.log('routesLength', routesLength);
```

If `routesLength` > 1 then it is not the first screen in stack

Or you can use `navigation.canGoBack()`

Answer (score 8):

There is an easier way:

```
if(this.props.navigation.isFirstRouteInParent()) {
    //a previous screen does not exist
} else {
    //a previous screen does exist
}
```

Comment: this solution is good enough in most cases, but what if i need the first route to be pushed into the stack, instead of goBack to ?

Comment: You can use simple and tradition way  NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'NEXT_SCREEN' }).

Answer (score 0):

```
const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
  routeName: 'NEXT_SCREEN',
  action: NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'NEXT_SCREEN', params: { previous_screen: 'CURRENT_SCREEN' } }),
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
```

Comment: Please provide a brief explanation of the piece of code.

Comment: You may very well have answered the question, but some comments about how it is you have answered would be benefitial to future readers

Answer (score 0):

It's completely working for me....
If you want to **find out previous route/screen name** from navigation stack in react native app so you can use this function.

```
export const previousRouteName = (navigation) =>{
  let navRoutes = navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().state.routes;
  if (navRoutes.length >= 2){
    return navRoutes[navRoutes.length - 2].routeName
  }
  return navigation.state.routeName
}
```

**How to use?**

```
previousRouteName(props.navigation);
```

Hope you like and helpful to you K00L ;)

Comment: this doesnt work, I dont understand why navigation.dangerouslyGetParent() doesnt work either, in both the cases result is undefined.