# How can I navigate to a specific screen when navigation stack is empty?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How can I do this:

```
if navigation stack is not empty
    this.props.navigation.goBack()
else
    this.props.navigation.navigate('CustomScreen')
```

Comment: I don't know if this fits your case, but take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48830382/react-navigation-check-if-previous-screen-exists?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a workaround solution is sending param from previous screen and in current screen check if that param exist

Screen1:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2', {prevScreen: 'Screen1'});
```

Screen2:

```
if(this.props.navigation.getParam('prevScreen', null))
    this.props.navigation.goBack();
else
    this.props.navigation.navigate('CustomScreen');
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function in `this.props.navigation` called `dangerouslyGetParent`. You can see it in the documentation [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#dangerouslygetparent-get-parent-navigator).

It states the following in the documentation:

> Another good use case for this is to find the index of the active
>   route in the parent's route list. So in the case of a stack if you are
>   at index 0 then you may not want to render a back button, but if
>   you're somewhere else in the list then you would render a back button.

So we can use the following to get the index of the route

```
this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().state.index
```

So without having to pass a parameter you can check where you are in the stack and then decide what to do.

```
// get the index of the route
let index = this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().state.index;
// handle the index we get
if (index > 0) {
    this.props.navigation.goBack();
} else {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('CustomScreen')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution now is simply checking the navigation.canGoBack().
It gives you a boolean to check if it is safe to go back.
ref: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#cangoback