# How to get previous route name from React Navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to get previous route name to my current screen. Because based on the previous screen name, I have to show/hide few objects in current screen.

To get previous screen name, I have tried following

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    if (navigation.state.params && navigation.state.params.previous_screen) {
       console.log('navigation.state.params.previous_screen', navigation.state.params.previous_screen);
    }
}
```

But, It's getting `undefined` in console log.

Any suggestions?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48830382/react-navigation-check-if-previous-screen-exists

Comment: I checked that, But, Not working, And showing undefined.

Comment: the below solution didn't work?

Comment: why are  you not accepting answers to your questions? if the provided answer doesn't work, at least comment and say it didn't work.

Comment: @TenTenPeter I already stated that I checked that, But, Not working, And showing undefined. Please check my above comment. It was not worked. I don't want to down vote their answers even if those are not worked.

Comment: can you share the code, that's giving you undefined, as this's working. I've added a demo too.

Comment: I will update you soon/

Comment: @AnilkumariOSReactNative please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and the code below by Junius L should answer your question.

Comment: Answer worked from Junius

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use `NavigationActions`

```
goToScreen = () => {

  const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
    routeName: 'Profile',

    params: { previous_screen: 'Home' }, // current screen

    action: NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Profile' }), // screen you want to navigate to
  });

  this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
  
};
```

call the above function in your `onPress`

```
<Text onPress={this.goToScreen}>Go to screen</Text>
```

In your other screen

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  
  const { navigation } = this.props;
  if (navigation.state.params && navigation.state.params.previous_screen) {

    this.setState({
      previous_screen: navigation.state.params.previous_screen
    });

  } else {
    console.log("ERROR");
  }
};
```

[Working demo](https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/excited-cashew)

Function version

```
const goToScreen = () => {
  // assuming that navigation is passed in props
  props.navigation.navigate('Settings', {
    previous_screen: 'Home'
  })
}
```

And access the params like

```
const Settings = ({ route }) => {
  const { previous_screen } = route.params;

  return ....
}
```

Comment: what can be solution of functional version of it.

Comment: The logic is the same, just set the prev routes in the params

Answer (score 24):

For Stack Navigators, I was able to dynamically get the previous route name in react-navigation v6 with:

```js
// `navigation` const is passed to the screen component or from useNavigation()
const routes = navigation.getState()?.routes;
const prevRoute = routes[routes.length - 2]; // -2 because -1 is the current route
```

Note: This is super useful for dynamically passing params back to a previous screen. Beware of nested routes though, the syntax is slightly different.

```js
if (prevRoute.name === "<Some Routing Key>") {
      navigation.navigate("<Some Routing Key>", params);
}
```

Comment: Why do I get "name is undefined" warning message for the prevCode ?

Comment: A better way to do this is using `useNavigationState` hook, due to the fact that they recommend not to use `navigation.getState()?.routes;` in that way.
[documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation-state)

Comment: @BartłomiejTuchowski the doc state "useNavigationState is a hook which gives access to the navigation state of the navigator which contains the screen". Which means it won't work for the parent navigator in nested navigators

Answer (score 8):

I got the proper way to found previous route (screen) name from current screen

```
 props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().state.routes
```

You will get the list(array) of screen from navigation stack. example like

Output is here

```
Array(0) [, …]
0:Object {routeName: "ROUNTE_NAME", key: "id-158*****6785-1"}
1:Object {params: Object, routeName: "Screen1", key: "Screen1"}
2:Object {params: Object, routeName: "Screen2", key: "Screen2"}
```

Thanks guys - K00L ;)

Answer (score 2):

Using navigation ref, you can have access to the root state. 
This block helps check if the target route is inside a nested navigation/route `(currentRoute?.state?.index > -1 && currentRoute?.state?.routes) ? currentRoute?.state?.routes?.[currentRoute?.state?.index]`

```
      const getRecentRoutes = ()=> {
        const rootState = navigationContainerRef.current?.getRootState();
        const routes = rootState?.routes;
        const previousRoute = routes?.[routes?.length - 2];
        const currentRoute = routes?.[routes?.length - 1];
        return {
          currentRoute: (currentRoute?.state?.index > -1 && currentRoute?.state?.routes) ? currentRoute?.state?.routes?.[currentRoute?.state?.index] : currentRoute,
          previousRoute: (previousRoute?.state?.index > -1 && previousRoute?.state?.routes) ? previousRoute?.state?.routes?.[previousRoute?.state?.index] : previousRoute,
        };
      };
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the below approach. This may be not the best approach but it does work.

```
let routes = this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetState().routes[0].state.history;
for (let idx = routes.length - 1; idx >= 0; idx--) {
  if (routes[idx].type == 'route') {
    let route = routes[idx].key;
    this.props.navigation.navigate(route.substr(0, route.indexOf('-')));
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
  routeName: 'Profile',
  action: NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Profile', params: { previous_screen: 'Home' } }),
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
```

Comment: You should comment the code you pasted here, how this code will answer OP question?

Comment: Code only answers are rarely helpful. Please comment your code or expound on why this is the solution to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using `react-navigation` v5 you can recurse the navigation state using the routes and index to find the current route. Once you have found the current route, an object that doesn't have any child routes, you can subtract 1 from the index to get the previous route.

The code to achieve this looks something like

```
const getPreviousRouteFromState = (route: NavigationRoute) => {
  let checkRoute = null
  if (route.state && route.state.index > -1 && route.state.routes) {
    checkRoute = route.state.routes[route.state.index]
    if (checkRoute.state && checkRoute.state.routes) {
      return getPreviousRouteFromState(checkRoute)
    }
    const previousRouteIndex = route.state.index - 1
    if (previousRouteIndex > -1) {
      checkRoute = route.state.routes[previousRouteIndex]
    }
  }
  return checkRoute
}
```

This strategy has some limitations - it will return the current route when navigating back due to limitations of a stack. It also returns the current screen when switching stacks.

Comment: Where are you using it? The route in a screen component only has a `key`, `name`, and `params` keys. No `state`.

Comment: I'm using it like this



`const navState = useNavigationState((state) => state)
const prevRoute = getPreviousRouteFromState({ state: navState })`

Answer (score 0):

Define some functions in `app.js | index.js`. Means initial screen

```
setActiveScreen = (activeScreen) => { 
    const previousScreen = this.state.activeScreen
    this.setState({activeScreen: activeScreen, previousScreen: previousScreen})
  }
  goBackScreen = () => {
    this.setState({activeScreen: this.state.previousScreen});
  }
```

And pass this functions to the navigation screens

```
<Stack.Screen >   
{(props) => <ComponentScreen goBackScreen={this.goBackScreen} setActiveScreen={this.setActiveScreen} /> }
</Stack.Screen>
```

Then run the `goBackScreen` before you use the `navigation.goBack()` in screens

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
this.props.goBackScreen()
this.props.navigation.goBack();
}}><Text>Click</Text> </TouchableOpacity>
```

`Note`: now you can get the previous screen name in activeScreen. It's just an example for the possibility. And you can try your own idea

---

Or you can pass the previous screen in params

```
navigation.navigate("home", {params: {previousScreen: '{{pass the currentScreen name}}'
```

then the next screen you can get it by `console.log(this.props.route.params)`

Answer (score 0):

```
const routes = navigation.getState()?.routes;

const prevRoute = routes[routes.length - 2];

if (prevRoute && prevRoute.name === 'previousScreen') {
          navigation.navigate('previousScreen');
} else {
          navigation.navigate('nextScreen');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In one of my projects I had tried to get previous screen name using index and routes.

I was using react-navigation 5.x version.

```
const { index, routes } = this.props.navigation.getState();
if( index && routes && routes[index-1].name){
 const previousScreenName = routes[index-1].name;
 ... code goes here
}
```