# Show a prompt before backpress exit in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

On React Native Android, whenever there are no screens left in the navigation stack and the user presses the hardware back button, the app exits. In this scenario, I want to show a prompt to the user asking if they really want to exit the app. What would be a good solution to this? Is there any library available? I'm using React Navigation v4.

Comment: This may help you to get more clarity https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48830382/react-navigation-check-if-previous-screen-exists

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use

```
import BackHandler from 'react-native'
var backBtnPress =1
```

use backhandler in your navigation component and check the condition if backbtn is pressed 2 times then do BackHandler.exitApp(); or else increment  backBtnPres+1, and use this for showing toast

```
ToastAndroid.show('do you really want to exit the app', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
```